# Have all of the Planet Express characters voice actors heads been featured in the Head Museum?

Tags: futurama

I've seen Katey Sagals head in a jar. Have all of the Planet Express characters voice actors heads been featured in the New New York Head Museum?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, to date Katey Sagal and Frank Welker (Nibbler) are the only heads of the cast that have been featured.

Billy West would have had been a fine head to sneak into this scene containing alphabetically organized heads in the W section but has yet to appear, though it does contain the Frank Welker appearance:

[image]

[List of heads in the New New York Head Museum](http://theinfosphere.org/Head_Museum#Known_resident_heads)

Comment: Incorrect: Frank Welker(Nibbler) is in the very shot you show above.

Comment: Oops, I was only looking for the main characters.  Updated.